# Is there a command-line method to tell if all current downloads in Chromium have finished?

Tags: chrome, download

Is there a command-line way to determine if all current downloads in Chromium have finished? By downloads, I mean downloading videos from Youtube. I don't want to just rely on looking at Chromium's Downloads tab to see if any downloading is in progress. Is there a command I can run or file I can check to see if a download is in progress?

Comment: As an extremely ad-hoc solution, how does something like "fuser -v your_download_wd/*” work for you? (Presupposing you can glob all your downloads.)

Comment: As a moderately less extreme solution, you may check network connections with lsof -p...

Comment: @LaszloValko That doesn't really work if you have tabs open with Ajax callbacks or a periodic reload, it's difficult to distinguish those from active downloads.

Comment: If this is specifically about Youtube and similar sites, use [`youtube-dl`](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/).

Answer (score 5):

If you know the paths of the files that you're downloading (for example, if you put them all in one directory) then you can check whether these files are still open.

```
lsof ~/Downloads
```

You can get a notification when Chrome has finished writing them (assuming [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait):

```
inotifywait -e close_write ~/Downloads
```

If you want to list all the pending downloads (or the finished ones), a clumsy way is to access Chrome's database. Since Chrome keeps the database locked, you can't access it directly (at least not with the command line `sqlite3` tool), you need to make a copy of the file, and there's a small chance that you'll get an inconsistent view, so this is not completely reliable but should be good enough for casual use.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
cp ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Downloads "$tmp"
echo 'select target_path from downloads where end_time is null;' | sqlite3 "$tmp"
rm "$tmp"
```

The best approach would probably be to make Chrome notify you when the download is over. The extension [Download Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-notifier/gdekiloeocnfnochnkldpkmllmfiaeke?hl=en) does that, but it has side additional effects and gives you a desktop notification, not something you can use easily from the command line. The key part of the code seems to be this:

```
chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function(obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty("state") && obj.state.current === "complete") {
        chrome.downloads.search({id: did}, function(items) {
            filename = items[0].filename;
            …
        }
    }
});
```

`…` would need to be filled in with a method to communicate with the outside world (create a file somewhere in the extension's directory, maybe), which is beyond my Chrome extension programming knowledge.

Comment: [***--use-simple-cache-backend***](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#use-simple-cache-backend) *Uses experimental simple cache backend if possible.* I guess it's still just a flag, but I've been using it more than a year.